# Intensity of fringes in a Double Slit experiment

Tags: optics, visible-light, double-slit-experiment, interference, superposition

I have learnt that the intensity of fringes in a double slit experiment depends on the following formula:
    $$I = 4i\cos^2(\delta/2)$$

But it turn out that the intensity of th consecutive fringe decreases with their distance from the center however the formula shows that it should not decrease
but all the fringes should have the same intensity.

[image: The decreasing intensity can be seen in this picture:]

Comment: Please have a look at [this link](http://hyperphysics.phy-astr.gsu.edu/hbase/phyopt/mulslid.html#c2). The light just doesn't undergo interference, but also diffraction.

Comment: @DhruvSaxena this can be the reason but still the equation that i have mentioned must hold true. Moreover if there is diffraction also taking place then what will be the expression for the intensity at a given point?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

For a single slit of width $b,$ illuminated by parallel light, the distant intensity of diffracted light at an angle $\theta$ to the normal is given by $$I=I_0 \frac{\sin^2 \beta}{\beta^2}$$
in which $\beta=\frac{\pi b \sin\theta}{\lambda},$ and $I_0$ is the intensity at $\theta=0$, that is the intensity on the axis.

This is modulated, if there are two such slits, parallel to each other and with centres distance $d$ apart, by the double slit factor, $$4\cos^2 \frac{\delta}{2}\ \ =\ \ 2(1+\cos \delta)$$
in which $\delta=2 \pi \frac{d \sin \theta}{\lambda}.$
So the overall intensity varies as
$$I=4I_0 \frac{\sin^2 \beta}{\beta^2}\cos^2 \frac{\delta}{2}\ \ \ =\ \ \ 2I_0 \frac{\sin^2 \beta}{\beta^2}(1+\cos \delta).$$